# compare key of an array with known value PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have an array(`$my_array`) and I want it should `print` as mentioned only its values is true i.e. In the given array it should print **I have a cow** and **I have a cat**. I want login something like if `cow` === `true` then print if `dog` === `true` then print ...

What is the best method in `PHP` to achieve this?

```
$my_array =[["cow", true ], ["dog", false ], ["cat", true ] ];
```

Comment: `foreach ($my_array as $value) {
 if ($value[1]) echo "$value[0]\n";
}`?

Comment: just keep it simple, use a `foreach` and an `if` statement

Comment: @Nick Thank you for the time. But I can't use foreach, because I am already inside a foreach loop! any suggestion other than foreach?

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for the time. But I can't use foreach, because I am already inside a foreach loop! any suggestion other than foreach?

Comment: @Rich please show the rest of your code; then it will be easier to determine what you really need

Answer (score 0):

according to the your problem you have an array

```
$my_array =[["cow", true ], ["dog", false ], ["cat", true ] ];
```

and you want to print only those values whose 1st index is `ture`.

so you can do like this it will print only the `0th` index value if the `1st` index value is true from `$my_array.`

```
array_map(function($arr){
    if($arr[1])
        print "I have a " . $arr[0] . "\n";
}, $my_array);
```

output will be

```
I have a cow
I have a cat
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @Nico Haase i have added some explanation.